# minimax algorithm tic tac toedoes not draw the response of the ai

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make an AI that looks for the best possible position to win the game using the minimax algorithm, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong so that the AI move isn't drawn

The code is separated into 3 functions, one when the player clicks and draws the x where he wants to then change it so that it is the turn of the AI, to then call bestScore that looks for which would be the best playing, calculating it from the minimax function

```
const boardAa = document.getElementById('board');
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');
const humanPlayer = "X";
const iaPlayer = "O";
let currentPlayer = humanPlayer;
const board = []


cells.forEach(cell => {
    cell.addEventListener('click', handleCellClick);
});


function handleCellClick(){
    if(this.textContent === "" && currentPlayer == humanPlayer){
        this.textContent = currentPlayer;
        board.push(Number(this.dataset.posicion));
        getBestMove();
    }
    
    console.log(board)
}


function getBestMove(){
    let bestScore = -Infinity;
    let bestMove;
    
    for(let i = 0; i < board.length ; i++){
        if(board[i] == ""){
            board[i] = iaPlayer;
            let score = minimax(board , 0 , false);
            board[i]= "";
           
        }
        if(score > bestScore){
            bestScore = score;
            bestMove = i;
        }
    }
    board[bestMove] = bestScore;

    return bestScore;

}


function minimax(board , depth , maximing){
    
    if(maximing){
        let bestScore = -Infinity;
        for(let i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
            if(board[i] === ""){
                board[i] = iaPlayer;
                let score = minmax(board, depth +1 , false);
                board[i]= "";
                bestScore = Math.max(score, bestScore);
            }
        }
        return bestScore
    }else{
        let bestScore = Infinity;
        for(let i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
        if(board[i] === ""){
        board[i] = currentPlayer;
        let score = minmax(board, depth +1, true);
        board[i] = "";
        bestScore = Math.min(bestScore, score);
      }
    }
    return bestScore;
    }
}
```

I've tried everything, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong so that the ia play isn't drawn
I even asked chatgpt but he can't tell me where the code error is